# Any way to stretch/collapse canvas grid in fabric js?

Tags: fabricjs

I am thinking of stretching/collapsing the canvas grid using input fields. I tried the grid.js also. But this is not for fabric js, though i tried hard.

Is it possible to stretch/collapse the canvas grid by user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a solution using some other guys solution those I did find in jsfiddle but I cannot find that reference link right now. I just have customized that solution to work with my code. Thanks to that guy. Here is my solution -

```
function draw_grid(grid_size) {

    grid_size || (grid_size = 25);
    currentCanvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
    currentcanvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();


    // Drawing vertical lines
    var x;
    for (x = 0; x <= currentCanvasWidth; x += grid_size) {
        this.grid_context.moveTo(x + 0.5, 0);
        this.grid_context.lineTo(x + 0.5, currentCanvasHeight);
    }

    // Drawing horizontal lines
    var y;
    for (y = 0; y <= currentCanvasHeight; y += grid_size) {
        this.grid_context.moveTo(0, y + 0.5);
        this.grid_context.lineTo(currentCanvasWidth, y + 0.5);
    }

    grid_size = grid_size;
    this.grid_context.strokeStyle = "black";
    this.grid_context.stroke();
}
```

I hope this will someone someday.